# Stating the domain of a function using set notation

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to write the domain of $f(x+y) = \frac{1}{1+ x + y}$ given $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+ x}$ using set notation.

I'm thinking first we'd have something like $Domain[ f(x) ] = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ -1 \}$ because division by zero is not defined.

If $f(x+y) = \frac{1}{1+ x + y}$, then $1 + x + y \neq 0$ by the same reasoning.

$1 + x + y \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow x + y \neq -1$

So, the domain of $f(x+y) = \frac{1}{1+ x + y}$ is the set of all x and y such that x and y are both real, x does not equal -1 and $x + y \neq -1$

Next, trying to separate x and y for the sake of writing the domain cleanly using set notation, we have:

$x + y \neq -1 \Leftrightarrow x \neq -( y + 1 )$

and

$x + y \neq -1 \Leftrightarrow y \neq -( x + 1 )$

Trying to write that using set notation, I would write something like this:

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ -1, -( y + 1 ) \} \\
y &= \mathbb{R} \setminus \{\ \  -( x + 1 ) \} \\
Domain[ f(x + y) ] &= x \cup y
\end{align}
$$

Is the above statement correct? Do we need different variables for the set of all values of x in the domain of f? A different variable for the set of all values of y in the domain of f?

Comment: The domain is part of a function's definition. The maximal subset of $\mathbb{R}$ on which $f(x) = 1/(1+x)$ is defined is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1\}$. It's unclear what you mean by "the domain of $f(x+y)$."

Comment: At first, I thought the book I was working off of was saying "Start with f(x), observe restrictions on its domain, then feed it (x+y) as input and observe any additional restrictions on its domain. Now, that I see the book's answer doesn't have the negative one in $\mathbb{R} \ { -1 }$ for the domain of f(x+y), I'm wondering if I'm even reading this correctly.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ -1 \}$ I think I dropped a few characters trying to type that on my phone...

Comment: Which book is it? What page?

Comment: Spivak Calculus, Chapter 3. Question 1 IV.

Comment: They're just asking you "What is $f(x+y)$?" Which is $1/(1+x+y)$, as you figured out.

Comment: That's true, but isn't what I'm asking in this post. :)  In this post, I'm doing "extra extracurricular activity", as it were: reading Spivak is already extracurricular; I'm not reading it for a grade. In addition to reading it, I'm trying to throw Symbolic Logic at Spivak to see what I can learn, in addition to just sorting through the book. I appreciate any help. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39867/discussion-between-alex-provost-and-studentstea).